# Getting table content using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to retrieve table content using the following python codes from this website: https://whalewisdom.com/filer/hillhouse-capital-advisors-ltd#tabholdings_tab_link

```
stat_table = soup.find_all('table', id_ = 'current_holdings_table', class_ = "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover")
```

But when I use len(stat_table), it returned me with a value of zero, indicating nothing was able to be retrieved from the website. Does anyone know where I went wrong? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see is loaded via JavaScript from another URL. To load the data, you can use this example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/holdings?id=hillhouse-capital-advisors-ltd&q1=-1&type_filter=1,2,3,4&symbol=&change_filter=&minimum_ranking=&minimum_shares=&is_etf=0&sc=true&sort=current_mv&order=desc&offset=0&limit=25'
data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for row in data['rows']:
    print('{:<5} {:<50} {:<15} {:<15}'.format(row['symbol'], row['name'], row['current_shares'], row['current_mv']))
```

Prints:

```
BGNE  BeiGene Ltd ADR                                    147035258.0     28823321625.74 
ZM    Zoom Video Communications Inc                      6856980.0       1738519000.0   
IQ    iQIYI Inc                                          46694629.0      1082848000.0   
BABA  Alibaba Group Holding Ltd ADR                      3930086.0       847720000.0    
PDD   Pinduoduo Inc                                      9863866.0       846714000.0    
UBER  Uber Technologies Inc                              19260700.0      598623000.0    
TAL   TAL Education Group American Depositary ADR        7906041.0       540615000.0    
JD    JD.com Inc ADR                                     7810402.0       470030000.0    
BILI  Bilibili Inc                                       9102063.0       421608000.0    
CBPO  China Biologic Products Holdings Inc               2962076.0       302665000.0    
ESGR  Enstar Group Ltd                                   1747840.0       267018000.0    
ALGN  Align Technology Inc                               790365.0        216908000.0    
APLS  Apellis Pharmaceuticals Inc                        5028289.0       164224000.0    
FGEN  FibroGen Inc                                       3955787.0       160328000.0    
BBIO  BridgeBio Pharma Inc                               4711604.0       153645000.0    
TSLA  Tesla Inc                                          130378.0        140783000.0    
CRM   Salesforce.com Inc.                                709495.0        132910000.0    
ZTO   ZTO Express Cayman Inc ADR                         3433592.0       126047000.0    
MDLZ  Mondelez International Inc. (Kraft Foods)          2431164.0       124305000.0    
VIE   Viela Bio, Inc.                                    2815868.0       121983000.0    
VIPS  Vipshop Holdings Ltd ADR                           5477392.0       109055000.0    
BPMC  Blueprint Medicines Corp                           1364631.0       106441000.0    
ARGX  Argenx SE ADS ADR                                  470000.0        105858000.0    
GOSS  Gossamer Bio Inc                                   7420974.0       96473000.0     
BEAM  Beam Therapeutics Inc.                             2966403.0       83059000.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me take a look at them.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of ('{:<5} {:<50} {:<15} {:<15}') ?

Comment: @JackyLaw That's formatting string, it means the first column is 5 characters wide, second 50 and so on...

Comment: I solved this problem completely now, really thank for your help, otherwise I might have to search for so long. On the other hand, if I want to also web crawl the next page's similar data and append at the end of the current page's data, what should I do? Could you suggest me a way for this?

Comment: @JackyLaw To not clutter the comment section, I suggest to open new question here on StackOverflow, where you put your code and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: May I ask how you generate the link of "https://whalewisdom.com/filer/holdings?id=hillhouse-capital-advisors-ltd&q1=-1&type_filter=1,2,3,4&symbol=&change_filter=&minimum_ranking=&minimum_shares=&is_etf=0&sc=true&sort=current_mv&order=desc&offset=0&limit=25" ?

Comment: @JackyLaw I saw this link in Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (Chrome has something similar too). There are all requests from the page, one of those requests was this link with data.

Comment: But there are 166 requests over there, how would you quickly determine this is the link?

Comment: @JackyLaw That's experience :) But I filtered only the Json requests - that's usually the format for exchanging data (not always though)

Comment: Wow, that's great to hear from your experience. Really thanks!